# Cake flavour options

Tags: cake, flavor

I want to make an easy cake. What flavor should I do it?
I have already tried strawberry, vainilla and chocolate cakes, but I want something different that its not too difficult.

Comment: Whatever sounds good! There's plenty of easy recipes out there. You can also try browsing recipes on a recipe site. If you run into any problems, just come back and ask - we can help with that!

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice Alice! We are primarily a Q&A site which deal only with questions that have a definite answer. Questions that are  opinion-based or does not have a "real" answer are considered off-topic and will most likely be close. However if you do run into a specific issue later on when making your cake, feel free to ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a vainilla cake with chocolate chips.